# Typescript Interface as series of OR interfaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

There is an interface which can be one of many interfaces

```
interface a {x:string}
interface b {y:string}
interface c {z:string}
type all = a | b | c
```

Later an object satisfies `all` because it is of type `c`

calling

```
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('z')) {
      return obj.z
    }
```

fails to compile because:

Property 'z' does not exist on type 'a'.

How do you solve this?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` isn't a type guard: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 1):

If in your case it is acceptable to replace `hasOwnProperty` by `in` and you don't want to define custom type guards - `in` [will do the job](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator):

```
interface a { x: string }
interface b { y: string }
interface c { z: string }
type all = a | b | c;

function foo(obj: all) {
  if ('z' in obj) {
    return obj.z; // obj type is narrowed to c
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjsg3sgHgLmQZzClAHNkBfAKFElkRQCMNkBPPQ4kMqm6eJZAmYAvdkVIVKYFgAcUcADYLkAXlTIAPsiZaEAbkqGYAVxAIwwAPYhkMS5YAUlhgCs8ihQEoMlZMmAwyA4A5MLB-jbOLt7ovn7IUBBgxlCRrgB0wnrIAPQ5yFHI0nL++MggcFBQlgDuEAAmRZaCcVR+icmpyKb1EDCgDQbkQA)

Answer (score 0):

`obj.hasOwnProperty('z')` doesn't by itself guarantee that `obj` satisfies the interface `c`. Suppose `obj` were to be declared as

```
var obj = { x: "foo"; y: "bar"; z: true };
```

In this case, `obj` satisfies `a` and `b`, but not `c` because `obj.z` is not a string.

You can, however, write your own type guards to get around this:

```
function isC(obj: all): obj is c {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('z');
  // or return 'z' in obj;
}

...

if (isC(obj)) {
  return obj.z; // this is fine
}
```